# Why on method is not working when selecting it through a static immediate parent for selecting a dynamically created anchor element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, pagination

**Static HTML Code:**

```
<div id="paging" >
</div>
```

I am using pagination plugin and making an ajax call [link to plugin](https://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/)

Ajax call to get the html Code:

```
function getEmployeeData(mode,firstName, employeeId, salary, departmentName,pageIndex) {
mode = mode || "";
firstName = firstName || "";
employeeId = employeeId || "";
salary = salary || "";
departmentName = departmentName || "";
pageIndex = pageIndex || 1;


$.ajax({
    url: "\Handler1.ashx",
    method: "POST",
    data: { type: 2, mode: mode, firstName: firstName, employeeId: employeeId, salary: salary, departmentName: departmentName, pageIndex: pageIndex },
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function (data) {
        $("#paging").pagination({
            items: data.totalCount,
            itemsOnPage: 5,
            cssStyle: 'light-theme',
            currentPage: pageIndex,
            prevText: "<<",
            nextText: ">>",
            selectOnClick: true,
            onInit: function () {
                bindEmployeeData(data);
            }
         });
       },
      error: function (response) {
         console.log(response);
      }
    });
  }
```

After page is loaded for the first time the dynamically created html inside my static div with **`id ="paging"`** is:

```
<div id="paging" class="light-theme">
   <span class="current prev">&lt;&lt;</span>
   <span class="current">1</span>
   <a href="#page-2" class="page-link">2</a>
   <a href="#page-3" class="page-link">3</a>
   <a href="#page-4" class="page-link">4</a>
   <a href="#page-5" class="page-link">5</a>
   <a href="#page-2" class="page-link next">&gt;&gt;</a>
</div>
```

In my js file, I am selecting each dynamically created **'a'** element and attaching a click event to them but it's not able to select when I am selecting via div **`id="paging"`** which is the static parent.

**Like this:**

```
$("#paging").on("click", "a", function (e) {
   var hrf_atr = $(this).attr('href');
   var page_cnt = hrf_atr.substring(6, hrf_atr.len);
   pageIndex = parseInt(page_cnt);
   getEmployeeData(2, "", "", "", "*", pageIndex);
});
```

But when I am using **'document'** as a static parent it's selecting perfectly.

**Code:**

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function (e) {
   var hrf_atr = $(this).attr('href');
   var page_cnt = hrf_atr.substring(6, hrf_atr.len);
   pageIndex = parseInt(page_cnt);
   getEmployeeData(2, "", "", "", "*", pageIndex);  
});
```

Please explain this strange behavior.

Comment: Can you share how you are generating HTML inside `#paging`

Comment: @Satpal added that part to the question, please go through.